# Response mapping to get object with dynamic path restkit

Tags: ios, restkit-0.20

how to i set response mapping to manager with path pattern ..if the getobjects at path is different from path pattern that is used to map the response.

```
[manager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:
@[[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:categoryMapping
 pathPattern:A
 keyPath:nil
 statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]]];



[manager getObjectsAtPath:A/ID
 parameters:nil
success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
NSLog(@" Category success");
[self.delegate didReceiveAssignedCategories];
}
failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Category failure");
}];
```

response mapping path ie:A  must be set to dynamic path used to getobject ie:A/ID .
ex:

Call 1)

A = /getAllCategories

A/ID = /getAllCategories/123

call 2)

A = /getAllCategories

A/ID = /getAllCategories/456

response mapping is same for 123, 456 
only while getting the objects i am using different urls ie: with id's attached.
 how to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 2 path patters which both return the same type of data then you can use the same mapping with 2 different response descriptors.

If you have 1 path pattern which can return 2 different types of data then you need to use `RKDynamicMapping` to 'intercept' the incoming data and decide which mapping is actually required.

---

From your edited question, 'pattern' is the important thing that you have misunderstood. You need to use a path pattern, not a static path:

```
@"getAllCategories/:identity"
```

Comment: there are two different mappings ...there's only one mapping with different getobjectatpath url's and the url's are dynamic.: attached with id's

Comment: You need to know the identity from the first response if you are going to use it in the second request.

Comment: response call 1)  {"responslist":[{"category:"rest"},{"category":"kit"}]} call 2)  {"responslist":[{"category:"abc"},{"category":"xyz"}]}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485014/map-upper-keypath-to-lower-keypath-restkit-v0-20 HELP WAIN

Answer (score 0):

1) First create response mapping like

```
[manager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:
@[[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:categoryMapping
pathPattern:@"getAllCategories/:categoryID"
keyPath:nil
statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]]];
```

2)Create Class with categoryID in it.

```
[CategoryRequest class]
```

3) create object of that class and set categoryID

```
CategoryRequest *categoryRequest = [CategoryRequest alloc] init];
categoryRequest.categoryID = @"123";
```

4)call getobject using that object

```
[manager getObject:categoryRequest 
path:@"getAllCategories/123" 
parameters:params 
success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                 NSLog(@"Success");
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure");
    }];
```

if another call is required to be  made for same mapping create object of of category request class set new category id and call get object using that categoryresquest and required path patter.