# Map upper keypath to lower keypath mapping attribute RESTKIT V0.20

Tags: ios, restkit-0.20

```
"Allocation":{

"UserID":"8bc2df34-b77a-4889-a2ab-559e24cc2d40",

"Answers": 
{
"SurveyInstanceAnswerID":"cb924a6a-ad61-4786-b5fb-00302c4fc7dc",
"SurveyInstanceAllocationID":"42e96cec-5a00-416c-8a96-488ab152e4f5",
"AllocationUniqueRef":"1ce53cdf-b33e-4594-a938-b60656b8b64c",
"SurveyContentID":"ccd07464-9718-4953-8e51-ad25fa00e053",
"AnswerValue":null,
 }
}
```

I have two classes **Allocation** with `userID` and **answer** with `answervalue` and `userID`.

I want to map `userid` present in allocations with `userid` in **answer** class.

I am using `rkEntitymapping` to map objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the current development branch (at the time of writing this feature hasn't been merged back to the master branch) you can use metadata to access the parent object during the mapping process:

```
@metadata.mapping.parentObject
```

So you can add a mapping:

```
@"@metadata.mapping.parentObject.UserID" : @"userId"
```

Comment: what if i need one more level up .

Comment: is there a way of mapping default value or value form entity ?

Comment: Defaults should be set in the core data model definition. I don't think you can move up an arbitrary number of levels.

Comment: ["@parent.@parent.attribute":"attribute"] works .. new restkit feature i guess

Comment: do u have any idea how to clear managedobjectcontext of restkit ? or may be refresh it ? i am facing error after deleting records from persistent store. restkit managed object context is not refreshed and new data pulled doesn't get saved in db.

Comment: You probably want a new question with details of how you are deleting from the store, threads, store setup...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533984/mapping-http-response-to-nil-target-object-restkitv0-20-3

Comment: Wain : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628451/update-or-save-managed-object-only-when-boolean-condition-is-met-when-restkit