# Main thread blocked after receiving objects restkit v0.20.3

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

Once  I pull data from server it gets saved in persistent store using `Entity mapping`.

Then I  `delete` those objects `manually`.

Now when  I try to pull the same data again i get the error  saying Mapping HTTP response to nil target object... `RKObjectmapperoperation`failed.

Main thread get's blocked may be there managed context in rest kit is not having object graph after deleting. I am not sure how to solve this error I tried resetting persistent store.

**UPDATE**

```
- (void)saveThreadedContext {
NSNotificationCenter *defaultCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

[defaultCenter addObserver:self
                      selector:@selector(mergeThreadedContextChangesIntoMainContext:)
                      name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                    object:self.threadedContext];

if ([[self threadedContext] hasChanges]) {

    NSError *error;

    BOOL contextDidSave = [[self threadedContext] save:&error];

    if (!contextDidSave) {

        // If the context failed to save, log out as many details as possible.
        NSLog(@"Failed to save to data store: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

        NSArray* detailedErrors = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSDetailedErrorsKey];

        if (detailedErrors != nil && [detailedErrors count] > 0) {

            for (NSError* detailedError in detailedErrors) {
                NSLog(@"  DetailedError: %@", [detailedError userInfo]);
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"  %@", [error userInfo]);
        }
    }
}

[defaultCenter removeObserver:self name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:[self threadedContext]];
self.threadedContext = nil;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PrivateMethods
- (void)mergeThreadedContextChangesIntoMainContext:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSLog(@"%@:%@ merging changes", self, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
 NSManagedObjectContext * context = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).managedObjectContext;
[context     performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:)     withObject:notification waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

I use `[self saveThreadedContext];` to save and merge thread context after deleting objects.

```
[context           performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:) 
        withObject:notification waitUntilDone:YES];
```

holds lock on `context` which causes the block when restkit tries to merge it's context.
wanted to know what type of concurrency to use while creating threadContext used to delete objects. i tried `waitunitdone:NO` and the block didn't arise again..need some explanation why

Comment: Please show your model setup (are you using an in-memory store for quick matching during mapping) and your mappings (do you have inconsistent `identificationAttributes`). Are you deleting and saving? Deleting from the persistent store context? From the main thread?

Comment: Deleting objects using background thread using threaded context of it's own .then i merge the changes with trump policy.how to update managed object contex of restkit so that it has the latest object graph.

Comment: What is returned by `managedObjectContext` in the app delegate (because it's called on a background thread)? How have you configured the MOC? Why are you deleting on a background thread?

Comment: got the error. i was not removing the observer after merging in coredata helper class.hence when restkit tried to merge it would call two notifications and hence block.