# Update or save managed object only when boolean condition is met , when restkit tries to update records

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit-0.20

I have `syncState` boolean attribute in my `Answers Entity` which is not mapped. I get records of `Answer Entity` from server using `RkEntity Mapping`. I want to `save/update` already existing records only if `syncState` of `already existing` records is `Synced` and ignore records fetched from server if syncState of already existing records is `UnSynced`.
I was thinking of overriding `willSave` of `Answers Entity` and ignore saving but that method can be used to update some records and not avoid saving managed object.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [KVC validation](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#key-value-validation) for this as it allows you to abort the mapping of individual objects so they are never candidates for saving rather than trying to manipulate the save. In particular, you need to set `discardsInvalidObjectsOnInsert`.