# RKResponseDescriptor set pathPattern

Tags: ios, restkit-0.20

the Restful Webservice that i'm using delivers an user id. For example if i want to get the User ID for the user "test" the request have to look like this:

*http://example.org/users/findByUsername/test*

Now i am using RestKIT 0.20 for my iOS App. Therefore i have to set a **Response Descriptor** like this:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *usrDescriptor =
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:usrmapping
                                             method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                             pathPattern:@"users/findByUsername/test"
                                             keyPath:nil
                                             statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[manager addResponseDescriptor:usrDescriptor];
```

My issue is that i don't want to set **pathPattern** including the parameter *test*. Instead i am looking for a solution that is independent of the value *test*
. Something like this:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *usrDescriptor =
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:usrmapping
                                             method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                             pathPattern:@"users/findByUsername"
                                             keyPath:nil
                                             statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[manager addResponseDescriptor:usrDescriptor];
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: just found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180735/response-mapping-to-get-object-with-dynamic-path-restkit

Comment: just found my solution here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180735/response-mapping-to-get-object-with-dynamic-path-restkit